# Balloon hint after hovering on gridview field

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have a simple gridview table, that shows data from one table only. It contains field named "comment" (of each product) and, since the comments can be very long, in gridview I show only first 50 characters. I would like, that after I hover on each comment, a balloon/bubble/not-sure-how-to-call-it appears, with the whole comment inside. Is it possible for GridView? No clicking, just right after hovering on comment.

```
<div class="comments">

    <?=
    GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            'place_rating',
            'comment:longtext',
        ],
    ]);
    ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please read these links to improve your question: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Tom no, I haven't tried anything, because I can't imagine any way to achieve this. That's why I'm asking if that's even possible, and if so, where can I find more info.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

Comment: @Ripper yes, that is exactly what I want. I don't know how to apply it to my gridview, though.

Comment: can you post that part with comment? I will post answer with your code edited.

Comment: @Ripper code added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="comments">

    <?=
    GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            'place_rating',
            // 'comment:longtext',
            [
                'attribute' => 'comment',
                'format' => 'longtext',
                'contentOptions' => function($data) {
                    // needs to be closure because of title
                    return [
                        'class' => 'cell-with-tooltip',
                        'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
                        'data-placement' => 'bottom', // top, bottom, left, right
                        'data-container' => 'body', // to prevent breaking table on hover
                        'title' => $data->comment,
                    ];
                }
            ]
        ],
    ]);
    ?>

</div>
```

Then in your in /views/layouts/main.php add this

```
<?php $this->registerJs("
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle=\"tooltip\"]').tooltip();
    });
", $this::POS_END, 'tooltips'); ?>
```

or add it to your .js file without php code ofcourse